# Overcoming Lack of

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am using **Google Sheets' Query** (G.Query) to summarise return on some capital investment  percentage from a log of transactions. I like to generate the complete result from **one single g.query statement** instead of a mix of g.query and formulas or multiple g.queries. It would be not just more elegant but much more flexible in many dynamic situations.

It seems that **g.query does not allow column alias**. Due to this reason, I have no idea to generate a second column based on results from the first column within the g.query sql statement. Referring to the image below. I am trying to generate Case 1 with a single SQL statement. So a possible solution is to an sql like Case 3, which does not work. I use a work around as in Case 4 to avoid repeating duplicated columns formula but it only works on a simple case. It would be much more elegant if Case 3.a works.

I am not sure if it is me not knowing g.query enough or is it real that g.query does not offer column Alias functionality. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Case 3** not working looks like a bug to me, considering that **Case 2** works just fine and the following.

Here is a workaround for you (`SUM(C)` and `SUM(B)` just swapped places in the fraction):

```
=QUERY(
  A2:D,
  "SELECT A, SUM(B) + SUM(C), SUM(D), (SUM(C) + SUM(B)) / SUM(D)
   WHERE A IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY A
   LABEL SUM(B) + SUM(C) 'Rent',
         SUM(D) 'Capital',
         (SUM(C) + SUM(B)) / SUM(D) 'Return, %'
   FORMAT (SUM(C) + SUM(B)) / SUM(D) '0.00%'",
  1
)
```

[image]

And another one using enclosing second `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY(
  QUERY(
    A2:D,
    "SELECT A, SUM(B) + SUM(C), SUM(D)
     WHERE A IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY A
     LABEL SUM(B) + SUM(C) 'Rent',
           SUM(D) 'Capital'",
    1
  ),
  "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col2 / Col3
   LABEL Col2 / Col3 'Return, %'
   FORMAT Col2 / Col3 '0.00%'",
  1
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have similar work around like what you have suggested in real life. There are many ways to work around including using google array function { range ; range} for extra column for the query statement, which is like a multiple query combo.  This is why my question is not just looking for a solution but more like searching for a more elegant solution using a "single" and "simple" query statement. The second purpose of the question is to verify if I have missed something serious. Anyway, if g.query does allow Alias for column, it would have been so much more elegant. :)